# IE11's Console reporting that I have more than one body tag

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I keep getting this message on the IE11 Console

> HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist
>   per document. File: Login, Line: 76, Column: 1

When I read the HTML, there is only one body tag. I read up on IE's 1514 message, and there isn't anything there that would cause this issue that I can find.

Is there a good tool to try to find out what IE is really complaining about? The best I can think of is that one of the libraries I am loaded may have something in script, but even then that doesn't make sense unless it is being added to the dom, and removed.

The only other thing I can think of, is that I am also getting an HTML1521, but that is momentary, because the script is still building the page. This is an SPA app, and all code happens between body and \body, That way I don't have to watch the body tag.

I haven't seen this in either Chrome or FF. If it weren't for the fact that I have to support IE I wouldn't be concerned about this message.

I have tried to post the code, but stripping the IP out of it for public exposure has broken everything, so rather than getting a public code review, I am looking for ideas in tools that may help find this, or blogs that may have useful information.

So far Google and Bing have not shown me anything that I don't already know, or already tried.

**[Edit - Added details from discussion below]**

- No conditional comments `<!--[if IE]...`
- By the time I see this error showing up in the console log, the page is fully rendered. So I don't get to see any intermediate rendering.
- Using Fiddler for that. I have confirmed that the server is pushing well formed html
- Frameworks being used:

  - UI.Bootstrap,
  - Twitter Bootstrap,
  - Angular.js,
  - Angular.UI
  - Angular.DragAndDrop
- Grabbed the HTML from Fiddler, and verified the HTML

  - `<body></body> only one pair`
  - there is a div with `<div class="container body-content"></div>` should not affect this rule.
  - validated there are no open tags and that there is only one body open and close tag.

Thank you jascher for helping to cover the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped supporting IE11 on that project. Customers were directed to Chrome and Firefox, and later Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have conditional comments on your page.

Like    `<!--[if IE]> ... <![endif]-->`
They are not supported in IE since IE10.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: No conditional comments.

Comment: It's hard to guess without the sources :)

Comment: One else guess - if you get HTML1521 during the page building it means that </body> tag appeared somewhere. Did you try to search </body> tag through the page source after you got this error?

Comment: Yes, it is hard to guess without source. Which is why I hate working on IP specific sites. :)
***
By the time I see this error showing up in the console log, the page is fully rendered. So I don't get to see any intermediate rendering. What I do know is that once the page has finished rendering, there is only on <body> and one </body> tag.

Comment: This is why I am hoping that someone has a tool that records a browser snapshot on each log post, so I can try to catch the problem as it happens. What is worst, is that Chrome and FF say there is no problem. So why is IE such a hater. :D

Comment: The next activity I recommend - to look at the network log and to find ajax responses with full html content(I mean <html><head...). If there are any, you can dig to the place where they are using.

Comment: I've been using Fiddler for that. It has confirmed that the server is pushing well formed html. I am assuming that is why Chrome and FF don't have a problem with the page. This is why I am concerned that this is a loading issue that one of the UI frameworks I am using is triggering. UI.Bootstrap, Twitter Bootstrap, Angular.js, Angular.UI. But when I checked with them, in their chatroom, no one else had seen this.

Comment: did you try filtering responses by "Show only HTML" and inspect them? Here is a example for msn.com with full html page in response - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oK_hzU7ooSQjRkTnMtV1hTV0E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just did that. There is only one `<body></body>` pair, but there is a div with `<div class="container body-content"></div>`. However, that CSS shouldn't affect this rule detection.

I also ran it through my tag validater, and there are no missing or open tags.

Answer (score 0):

I know that 7 years elapsed but I had the same problem today so I share my answer.

I think you have some invalid html tag in your head section which is identified as starting the body part and when the real body part starts IE11 recognize it as a second one that is why the more body warning. Here is a very simple (but invalid) HTML file which easily demonstrates the situation what you and me also faced with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <p><title>My Title</title></p>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><style type="text/css">.blue {color: blue;}</style><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <H1 class="blue">It is blue when older than IE9</H1>
</body>
</html>
```

Please look at the invalid paragraph HTML tag in the head section around the title fragment.

The conditional statement is not a problem as Allaksai mentioned above.

If you delete the invalid paragraph tag from the head section, the more body warning will be disappeared.

Use the F12 button and check with your browser also look carefully the head section and also check the DOM layout tab in the developer tool. You will see that the paragraph part goes into the DOM body part with the title element.

The same thing happens when you are using bootsfaces which has default mobile support and put the viewport element like this into the head section:

```
<p><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /></p>
```

which is also invalid... but this is an other question of course.

Hope my answer could help anyway.

Comment: That code is long gone, so I cannot review it again. However, I had enough people on it that they were convinced that this was a browser rendering issue and not my code. Specifically, since this was only on IE11 that I ran into this problem.

Comment: FTR: A lot that I did 7 years ago is long gone, as most of my UX work is done in Angular 10+.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Brian for your feedback. Yes, 7 years is quite a lot in software development.